# How do I register my scanner in Simple Scan?

Tags: linux-mint, scanner, brother

Recently I decided to switch from Windows 10 to Linux Mint 20.1.

When I open up the Document Scanner utility it says that it cannot detect any scanners.

I have a Brother MFC-L2700DW. Although it isn't recognized as a scanner, it does show up as a printer.

Comment: You probably need some linux specific scanner drivers: https://www.brother.de/support/mfc-l2700dw/downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [scanner drivers from here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl2700dw_us_eu_as&os=128&mid=true):

```
wget https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006645/brscan4-0.4.9-1.amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.9-1.amd64.deb

wget https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006652/brscan-skey-0.3.1-1.amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.3.1-1.amd64.deb

wget https://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2-0.all.deb
 sudo dpkg -i --force-all brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.2-0.all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add your user to the `scanner` group. As root

```
adduser your-username scanner
```